# BLOGGER - Use custom variables inside <b:if> tag?

Tags: variables, conditional-statements, blogger

I am trying to create a conditional statement depending on the value of a custom variable called "pp". However I received this message and my widget cannot be loaded:

The expression 'pp == "left"' is not valid.

This is my code:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var pp = "left";
    </script> 

<b:loop index='postcont' values='data:posts' var='post'>
        <b:if cond= 'pp == "left"'>
          <b:include name='leftpost'/>
        <b:elseif cond='pp= mid'/>
          <b:include name='midpost'/>
        <b:else/>
          <b:include name='rightpost'/>
         </b:if>
    </b:loop>
```

Is there any way to use custom variables inside  tag? Or any other option to achieve what I am looking for.

Thank you.

BR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [b:with](https://bloggercode-blogconnexion.blogspot.com/2016/03/tag-b-with.html) tag to define a blogger variable

```
<b:with var='pp' value='"left"'>
  <b:loop index='postcont' values='data:posts' var='post'>
    <b:if cond='data:pp == "left"'>
      <b:include name='leftpost'/>
      <b:elseif cond='data:pp == "mid"'/>
      <b:include name='midpost'/>
      <b:else/>
      <b:include name='rightpost'/>
    </b:if>
  </b:loop>   
</b:with>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!